# System Gnome extensions path

Tags: gnome-shell-extension, 20.10

Where are the system provided Gnome extensions stored? I can only find the ones I've installed myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System-wide Gnome shell extensions are located in:

`/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

Gnome shell extensions installed by the user are located in:

`$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept the answer once I've checked it out

Answer (score 2):

the system-installed extensions are in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions is the path you're looking for